# docker mount volumns but keep files inside the docker container

Tags: php, docker

I use Dockerfile to build an image of php, but as the default, PHP don't have a php.ini file. So I need to create it. Now I have three ways to do this:

1. use RUN command in Dockerfile `RUN cp /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini-production /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`. But this way still use a default setting, I can't edit it (or edit it and commit container).
2. use COPY command in Dockerfile `COPY php.ini /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini`. OK, now I can edit the config and then build image, but if I need to change some setting, I need rebuild image
3. use volumn args, add this in docker-compose.yml `- $PWD/php/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/my_config`. By this way, I can edit php.ini anytime and just reload config file. But, the best way I wonder is `- $PWD/php/conf.d:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d`. the first way will create a new sub folder in docker container, the second way will delete the *.ini file that originally in the folder

I want to know is here some way that could mount volumn and don't delete the file in container (the second way of 3 but don't delete file)

Comment: You should be able to use the same volume-mount syntax to mount a single file.

Comment: @DavidMaze I forgot this way that just only mount a file. Now it works. Thanks you for your remind

Answer (score 1):

Actually the files are not `deleted` from the subfolder. The volume is mounted over it.

[Reference](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/4361)

What you can do is, assign a separate folder for your `*.ini` files, and reference it from the main `php.ini` file. So every time you reload php, it goes to `php.ini` and from there it gets your dedicated config folder and loads all the `*.ini` files from there.